# How to remember hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

I forget them all the time in solving PDE.
Can someone provide a way to remember them:
$$
\cosh\left(x\right)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
\qquad \text{ and } \qquad
\sinh\left(x\right)=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
$$

Comment: If you know some complex analysis, then you can recall that $\cosh x = \cos ix$ and use $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$. Similar for $\sinh x = i \sin ix$.

Comment: I always remember as $e^x=\cosh{x}+\sinh{x}$ and that helps me remember that the $e^{-x}$ terms cancel...(have opposite signs...)

Comment: And also remember that $\cosh x$ is always positive ( and even)  so it must be a sum of exponentials

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: hem, what about $e^x=\sinh x+\cosh x$ ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust, what do you mean?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: that the formula can't tell you which is which, unless you know that the cosine comes first and has the $+$.

Comment: Okay well then how about also knowing that $e^{-x}=\cosh{x}-\sinh{x}$?  Certainly this would provide the information....just add the two together and you have cosh

Comment: Maybe think about what the graphs look like and the range of the functions.

Comment: actually, the way to remember these for PDEs is just that $y''-\beta^2y=0$ has solutions $y=\cosh (\beta x)$ and $y=\sinh (\beta x)$ plus the derivative properties of cosh and sinh.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: this is the exact same memorization effort than the original formulas.

Answer (score 9):

Is your problem remembering the formula itself, or just which of the two has the "+" and which has the "-" ?

If the latter, one would be

c**o**sh == p**o**sitive

si**n**h == **n**egative

Comment: Upvoted, though this should be a comment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why should it be a comment? The Questions was "Can you provide a way to remember". The answer provides one. (OK, from a strictly formal-logical point of view the answer should just have been "YES, I can." ;c) )

Comment: Because one should wait for the OP's answer. It may turn out that your answer is not answering :) [Just like I prematurely answered myself.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust Seems 'rules' are slightly different here than on other SE sites then. Sorry, didn't know. (And doesn't make much sense to me now, but I haven't spent much time on this comunity yet.)

Comment: I don't claim that my statement follows official guidelines. From personal experience, it is often a waste to answer an ambiguous question.

Comment: @BmyGuest, thank you, your trick is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Remember sinh(x) is "smaller" than cosh(x)!

Comment: nice. I should include this in my standard soundbite for these.

Answer (score 1):

The definition does not help much at beginning, I also felt that way earlier in college. One graphical way is their behavior as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Draw graphs of $ e^x, e^{-x}$, also draw sum (double the average) and difference and see their asymptotic behavior. $ \cosh x$ seems to be snugly or *evenly* suspended between them and $ \sinh x$ is *odd function* like the cubic $ y= x^3$ .

Answer (score 1):

Like their trigonometric counterparts, the cosine is even and the sine is odd and they share the value at $0$.

If you can't remember the latter, use the Euler formula

$$e^{i0}=\cos(0)+i\sin(0)=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is general, if $x, -x \in \text{dom}(f)$ then we have the following identity:
$$ f(x) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left( f(x)+f(-x) \right)}_{even} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \left(f(x)-f(-x) \right)}_{odd}$$
when we apply this identity to the exponential function it yields the **hyperbolic cosine** and **hyperbolic sine** functions which are even/odd in the same fashion as sine an cosine:
$$ e^x =  \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left( e^x+e^{-x} \right)}_{\cosh(x)} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \left(e^x-e^{-x} \right)}_{\sinh(x)} $$
The reason for the term **hyperbolic** is that these functions parametrize hyperbolas in the same way ordinary trigonometric functions parametrize circles:
$$ x = \cosh t, y = \sinh t \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2-y^2= \cosh^2t - \sinh^2 t = 1.$$
But, this is only a parametrization of $x>0$ branch of the hyperbola... as the story goes, cosh and sinh are similar to cosine and sine, but, not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This approach always worked for me.
[image]